# batch_size = x.shape[0] AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

This code  combine image and mask  for image detection?
How can i correct that error?

> batch_size = x.shape[0]  AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'

This is the code used for training:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
            rescale=1. / 255,
            shear_range=0.2,
            zoom_range=0.2,
            horizontal_flip=True)
train_datagen_1 = ImageDataGenerator(
            rescale=1. / 255,
            shear_range=0.2,
            zoom_range=0.2,
            horizontal_flip=True)


train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            train_data_dir,
            target_size=(200, 150),
            batch_size=1
          )
train_generator_1= train_datagen_1.flow_from_directory(
            train_data_dir_1,
            target_size=(200, 150),
            batch_size=1)
train_generator_2 = zip( train_generator, train_generator_1)

model.fit_generator(
            train_generator_2,
            steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
            epochs=50)
```

This is the model I'm using:

```
model = Sequential() 
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(200, 150, 3))) 
model.add(Activation('relu')) 
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) 
model.add(Flatten()) 
model.add(Dense(20)) model.add(Activation('relu')) 
model.add(Dropout(0.5)) 
model.add(Dense(90000)) 
model.add(Activation('sigmoid')) 
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: File "C:\Users\Wael\Anaconda2\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1833, in fit_generator
    batch_size = x.shape[0]

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: x is defined inside fit_generator  function

Comment: the model accept image of size 200 X 150  and it must produce output image of size 200 X 150. Images is saved on the hard disk.

Comment: A sequential model doesn't handle two inputs. Do you really want two inputs? Your description above seems like "one image (one input) --> one image (one output)"

Comment: one image as input and one as output but output is a vector of 1 X (200*150*3). when i pass train_generator only to fit the model run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, since your model has only one output, you cannot join two generators like that.

- A generator must output things like `(input,output)` in a tuple.
- Yours is outputting `((input1,output1), (input2,output2))`, tuples inside a tuple.

When your model gets a batch from the generator, it's trying to get the shape of what it thinks is the `input`, but it finds `(input,output)` instead.

**Working the generator:**

You can probably create your own generator like this:

```
def myGenerator(train_generator,train_generator1):

    while True:

        xy = train_generator.next() #or next(train_generator)
        xy1 = train_generator1.next() #or next(train_generator1)
        yield (xy[0],xy1[0])
```

Instantiate it with:

```
train_generator2 = myGenerator(train_generator,train_generator1)
```

---

Now, you're going to have real trouble with the output shapes. If you're working from image to image, I recommend you work with a purely convolutional model.

A convolutional layer outputs `(Batch, Side1, Side2, channels)`, which is the shape you are working with in your images.

But a dense layer outputs `(Batch, size)`. This can only work if you reshape it later with `Reshape((200,150,3))` to match your "true images".

Hint: a Dense 20 in the middle of the model may be too little to represent an entire image. (But of course it depends on your task).

A possible model from this task is:

```
Conv
... Maybe more convs
MaxPooling
Conv
... Maybe more convs
MaxPooling
Conv

......

UpSampling
Conv
...
UpSampling
Conv
....
```

Every convolution with `padding='same'` to make your life easier. (But since you have one dimension being 150, you will have to manage padding the values at some point, because when you reach 75, the MaxPooling will remove/add one pixel (75 cannot be divided by two).

Comment: https://keras.io/models/sequential/  i write the same code in this link,

Comment: Many thanks for your perfect answer . but the first layer has the following error   ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_71_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (200, 150, 3)

Comment: The model is always expecting many samples. In truth, it's expecting `(None, 200, 150, 3)`, where `None` is the batch size. You cannot pass just a single image to the model, but a batch of images. If you do have only one, reshape them like `(1,200,150,3)`

Answer (score 9):

The selected answer is inaccurate. The reason why the code is failing is not because the tuples are of the `((input1,output1), (input2,output2)), ...)`, but because they are of the type `(((input1, class1), (input2, class2), ...), ((output1, class1), (output2, class2), ...))`.

You could have fixed your problem by simply adding `class_mode=None` to your `flow_from_directory` calls.

Comment: I know the comments are meant for "more useful" posts, but damn! You're a hero! I almost built a custom generator.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `class_mode=None` from `flow_from_directory()` could get it fixed:

```
 from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

 train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
      rescale=1./255,
      shear_range=0.2,
      zoom_range=0.2,
      horizontal_flip=True)

 train_image_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('path/to/data',
      target_size=(256, 256), 
      class_mode=None, 
      batch_size=4)
```

Comment: If `categorical` is related to multiclass classification, why setting it as such cause this error? Why `None` would be required?